# CRC8 on uneven number of bits - initial 0xff

Tags: crc

on **nRF24**, **CRC**-1 byte use polynome *x^8+x^2+x^1+1* with initial *0xff*.
This has to be done on an eneven number of bits. How is that calculated ? I cannot get same result. For instance : in binary

on : 000000000000000100010000000000000100000100000100000111111
**nRF24** will give a **CRC8** of : 01110110 (0xbb)

Any idea how it is calculated ?

Comment: That's 0x76, not 0xbb.

Answer (score 1):

This produces `0x76` from the data:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned crc8bit(unsigned crc, unsigned bit)
{
    crc ^= bit << 7;
    return (crc & 0x80 ? (crc << 1) ^ 7 : crc << 1) & 0xff;
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned n, crc;
    unsigned char data[] = "000000000000000100010000000000000100000100000100000111111";

    crc = 0xff;
    for (n = 0; n < sizeof(data) - 1; n++)
        crc = crc8bit(crc, data[n] & 1);
    printf("crc = %02x\n", crc);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: shame on me for 0xbb instead of 0x76.

Comment: It works, was wrong with my understanding of polynome x⁸+x²+x+1